# Unresolved external symbols when moving from vs2010 toolset to vs2017 toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017, command-line-interface

I have a C++ and a CLI project that use vs2010 platform toolset.
I want to move them to vs2017 toolset.

The C++ project compiles fine, but the CLI project throws numerous "unresolved external symbol" errors.

Anyone knows why this happens?

Example of a few errors:

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __cdecl __std_exception_copy(struct __std_exception_data const *,struct __std_exception_data *)" (?__std_exception_copy@@$$J0YAXPBU__std_exception_data@@PAU1@@Z)
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __purecall
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__strerror
```

Comment: Make sure that all dependencies of your new project were compiled with VS2017.

Comment: The question marked as duplicate does not answer the problem.
Anyway, I managed to resolve the issue by adding these dependencies: vcruntime.lib ucrt.lib

Comment: Seems like a failure in the project upgrade wizard.